# Virtual field not working with Azure

Tags: content-search, azure-search, search-facet

Currently, I'm using facet to filter the search result. The result works perfectly fine with SOLR but when I switch to Azure it doesn't work anymore. The result shows all although I added filter criteria. While troubleshooting this by debugging, I found that the virtual field **content_type** is missing from Cloud Field Name Map, then I assume that the virtual field cannot generate in Azure Search or I missed some configuration with it. I hope to receive feedback from you guys. Thank you very much.

Ps: I think the issue comes from item **[facet.FieldName]**. This field cannot be generated when queryable is executed.

Below is the source code for filtering by facet
[image]

My facet is defined in Sitecore content as below
[image]

and this is its configuration
[image]

and **Cloudfieldmap** cannot find virtual field **content_type**
[image]

Comment: For the first part, did you try 'Filter' instead of 'Where'?

Comment: The line facetValuePredicate should be PredicateBuilder.False<ISearchResultItem>(); It is True for And() and False for Or().

Comment: Hi Tamer, I try 'Filter' instead of 'Where' but the result is the same. Hi Chris, I also try your approach but it's also the same

Comment: Well you're going to have to do some debugging: try removing all predicates and just add one where statement predicate on this field

Comment: Azure Cognitive Search will be discontinued in the future and Sitecore will no longer provide support for this service in future releases. https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/sitecore-azure-search-overview.html#:~:text=Azure%20Cognitive%20Search%20will%20be,Microsoft%20Azure%20Cognitive%20Search%20service.